# How to view exceptions and application crashes on iphone

Tags: iphone, console-application

My app works ok on simulator and when my iphone is connected to the mac. When I disconnect the iphone and run it as stand alone on device, it crashes.
I would like to check those console messages after the crash. I remember seeing other application crashes inadvertently in itunes(I guess), but do not remember how I got there.

How do I check these exceptions or error messages either in the phone or using itunes on the computer?

Thanks,

Comment: Found it, its in the Xcode under Window -Organizer - Device logs. Leaving the question here in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest connecting your device to your development machine, then open up the XCode Organizer: In XCode -> Window -> Organizer. Click the device, click on "Device Logs". View.